# about spark remote submit app confuse

Tags: apache-spark

my situation as follows:

i have a spark cluster  ,  it is on Linux Systems .

but i test my app on Windows , now i submit it to remote spark cluster , it is not work and always print flollows log :

```
 15/08/04 19:33:09 WARN ReliableDeliverySupervisor: Association with remote system [akka.tcp://sparkMaster@h1:7077] has failed, address is now gated for [5000] ms. Reason is: [Disassociated].
```

my code :
 [image]

who know this problem ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After two days of exploration , I have found the way to solve the problem.

the most direct cause is that scala version is inconsistent , i found spark1.4.0 depend scala2.11.x , so i need recomplie spark source to suuport scala2.11.x

Follow the steps outlined below:

1 => dev/change-version-to-2.11.sh

2 => mvn -Pyarn -Phadoop-2.6 -Dscala-2.11 -DskipTests clean package

3 => make sure client scala version the same to server scala version